# Elementary OS Odin installation does not start

Tags: boot, intel, ssd, odin, secure-boot

thanks for help me. I have a new PC with this configuration.

Intel Core I5-11400 2.6 Ghz
Mb 1200 Gigabyte H510m - S2h
Ddr-4 16 Gb 2666 Hikvision
Ssd 512 Gb Intel 660p M.2 Nvme

The installation does not start after syslinux reboot the PC. the screen "try or install elementary OS" is the only screen I see.
I tryed to install in a PC with other Gigabyte mother but with a SATA SSD and run ok. It is possible to think the problem is this Intel SSD ?

I have already disabled the secure boot option.

Do you have any suggestion  ?
Thanks you!!

Comment: Sorry. the DDR memory are 32 GB with 3200 Mhz

Comment: Your system may be a bit too new for the kernel. One way to check would be to create a bootable USB of a distro with a newer kernel, such as [the recently released Ubuntu 21.10](https://releases.ubuntu.com/21.10/) and see if that installer can boot. If it can, then you may need to wait a little bit until the more recent kernel is rolled into Elementary 6.

Comment: Hello!. ok I will try to install Ubuntu 21.10 and I will wait for Elementary OS. Thanks You very much for your answer!!

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 does not start too...